# Carro de Compras Problema Con el Post gran tamaño

Tags: php, javascript, post

Buenas Tardes, tengo un problema con una  web que es similar a un carro de compra, donde los usuarios encargan mas de 150 productos diferentes por compra.
Todo esto se pasa por Post. MI gran problema es que algunas veces cuando son muchos productos el post me llega cortado, no me lo guarda completo.
Problema con la estructura del formulario se que no es, php.ini lo modifique para tener mas mb en el post.

Nosé si alguien me recomienda otra forma de pasar todo, si ir grabando directamente con js en session u otra forma.

Gracias

Comment: Además del máximo tamaño de POST, en el `php.ini` puedes probar modificando algo en tu webserver. Por ejemplo nginx tiene el parámetro `client_max_body_size` que por defecto es `1MB`. Otros webservers deben tener su propia manera de setear esto.

Answer (score 0):

A parte del tamaño en MB del post también existe otra limitante en php que se puede configurar el número de variables que se pueden enviar por get/post **max_input_vars** busca este valor en tu php.ini y prueba aumentándolo, por que según describes si guarda los valores pero no todos es posible que sea este valor que esté muy limitado. Si fuera el post_max_size te daría un error y no guardaría nada.